# QGIS: Preserving the band values in Hillshade

Tags: qgis, raster, qgis-processing

I used Raster -> Analysis -> Hillshade without changing any default values and I realised that the elevation data has changed from actual metres to 1 to 255:

[image]

Is it possible to preserve the values?

Comment: What do you mean by preserve the values ? Hillshade is just an indication of the shadow level as a "0 to 1 factor", so it has no direct relation with the height in meters. If you want to scale the 1-255 to any other scale, you can use Raster / Raster Calculator to multiply your values by a given factor.

Comment: I mean that the original DTM layer has 0 to 2737 so I thought HIllshade would be the same? Not 0 to 255..

Comment: Hillshade ≠ Elevation : http://www.geography.hunter.cuny.edu/~jochen/gtech361/lectures/lecture11/concepts/hillshade.htm

Comment: You can use symbology to show your DTM as a hillshade: Layer Properties-Symbology-Render Type-Hillshade.  This is just for display, the DTM values aren't affected.  I prefer the results of creating a separate hillshade using the GDAL tool which produces a new raster with values from 1-255.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DTM is a "Digital Terrain Model" showing elevation values varying from 0 m to 2737.419922 m. Hillshade won't show elevations. Take a look in the definition below.

> The hillshade function produces a grayscale 3D representation of the
> terrain surface, with the sun's relative position taken into account
> for shading the image. Hillshading is a technique for visualizing
> terrain determined by a light source and the slope and aspect of the
> elevation surface. It is a qualitative method for visualizing
> topography and **does not give absolute elevation values**.

(Source: [ArcGIS Website](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/raster-and-images/hillshade-function.htm))